# Changing button text onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, togglebutton

I would like to enable a `dark mode` feature on my website by using a `toggle button`. I already got `dark mode` to work now I would like to have the button say `Turn on dark mode` when it is off and then `Turn off dark mode` when it is on.

```js
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
}

.dark-mode {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Turn on dark mode</button>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("myButton1").value="Turn off dark Mode";`

Comment: You place that in the function that gets fired when you click the button, make it a switch if he value doesnt already equal "Turn off dark Mode" then set the value to "turn on dakr mode" and vice versa

Comment: @Bendars answer does a variation of what I said which is better

Comment: @Kevin Hernandez Ori Drori's javascript function worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.body;
   var btn = document.getElementById("modeSwitcher");
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
   if(element.classList.contains("dark-mode"))
    btn.innerHTML= "Turn off dark mode";
   else 
    btn.innerHTML= "Turn on dark mode";
}
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
}

.dark-mode {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="modeSwitcher">Turn on dark mode</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the global `.dark-mode` class on the body, to change the text on the button. Use a pseudo-element (`::before`), and set it according the existence of `.dark-mode` on the body:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}

.dark-mode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

body.dark-mode .mode-button::before {
  content: 'Turn off dark mode';
}

body:not(.dark-mode) .mode-button::before {
  content: 'Turn on dark mode';
}
```

```html
<button class="mode-button" onclick="myFunction()"></button>
```